# how to compare two timestamp values from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a db with time stamp values in this format: `0000-00-00 00:00:00` When I add this to the db I add a minutes to the current time. Now I need to check if the current time has passed the value added to the db. (x minutes passed)..

example add to db:

```
$time = strtotime ("+2 minutes");
$mysql_time = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

Then I get that value from the db. And need to compare current time with that value. I used to use unix values like this: `if(time() <= $unix_time){...}` but now, I want to compare timestamp values instead.. Something like `if(timeMysql() <= $mysql_time){..}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a function UNIX_TIMESTAMP that'll convert `0000-00-00 00:00:00` formatted value to linux timestamp integer.

You can use this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp